# Facebook graph api friends of friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to select friends of friends of an user from Facebook. Is there an easy way to do it without searching for a friend list for every friend list of the actual user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean with "searching for a friend list for every friend", but what you want to achieve is not possible at all. You don´t even get all friends anymore, only those who authorized your App too, with the `user_friends` permission. It is NOT possible to get friends of friends (second degree).

Comment: So, in facebook sdk i just get friends who authorized my app? Even in facebook graph? For ios or node.js? And if i use FQL? And a friend of my friend who authorized my app? Is that possible?

Comment: FQL is deprecated and you need to learn the difference between the API and the SDKs. the SDKs are just easier ways to use the API, in different languages. as i said, you can only get friends who authorized your app, and you can´t get friends of friends. period.